# what happens on form submits in Coldfusion?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, coldfusion, process

I'm struggling a little to understand the server-side of things using Coldfusion8 and thus far doing client-side stuff only.

Say I have a basic Coldfusion page layout like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function foo() {  docoument.myForm.submit(); }
</script>

<cfif isdefined("sendMyForm")>
    ... running coldfusion...
    ... displaying something...
</cfelse>
   <form action="nextPage.html" method="post" name="myForm">
       <input type="text" name="formContains" />
       <input type="hidden" name="sendMyForm" value="yup" />
       <input type="button" name="sender" value="send" OnClick="foo() /> 
   </form>
</cfif>
```

**Question:**
What actually happens *server-side* when I submit the form? Is the page getting "re-loaded" and the *cfif* causes coldfusion to run and display results? Just looking for some basic info so I understand what's happening.

Thanks for hints!

Comment: You have been asking many questions about CF. What sort of project are you working on? Such as...making a website more dynamic, building a web application, maintaining an existing syste, etc?

Comment: I'm asking because many of the examples out there like this lend themselves more to a slightly dynamic website. For a web application with many interfaces you would likely not want to organize the code in this manner. Much better alternatives would use a central controller model such as [FW/1](https://github.com/seancorfield/fw1/wiki) or even as simple as this [switch/case controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927270/coldfusion-whats-the-advantage-of-front-controller-design-over-page-controller).

Comment: I second the FW/1 recommendation - learning FW/1 alongside CF should help to simplify things and make them easier to digest. Also, there are small example FW/1 applications you can look at to help understand how things work.

Comment: @DanRoberts - I have an existing system, which I had developed for me. It's a working web application (CF8/MySQL), but the UI is just out of date and since I have more or less written a new one, I'm now trying to integrate my new UI (solely Jquery Mobile based) with the current system. It is fairly complex though (~ 50 cfm pages, fairly content heavy).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Think of CF and most web servers/systems as accepting input (url/get, form/post, cookie, etc) and returning output (html, json, text, etc). That cycle generally repeats. Someone types in a web address in a browser, request goes to server, page returned with form. User hits submit, request goes to server, page returned with results. User clicks link, request goes to server...and on and on.
2. You need to have the form action submit back to itself due to the way the if statements are organized.  If in form.cfm file then action should be form.cfm. Unless you setup specific mappings in the webserver to have CF handle html files then the file will need to be .cfm
3. You mention leaving the action attribute out all together submits the form back to the same page but I don't believe this works in every browser.
4. It is also more common/safer to have form method="post", then check for `structkeyexists(form, "fieldname")`

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Not the latest links, but valuable information.

[http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=523839l](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=523839)
http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Email_contact_form_in_ColdFusion-16882.html

I was trying to understand how form submits work in Coldfusion. If the page structure is:

```
<cf "inputName" = "someValue">
   ... run the from logic
</cfif>

<cfoutput>
  <form>
    <input name="inputName" />
    ... more form
 </form>
</cfoutput>
```

So when I submit the form without action, *it gets submitted to the page it's on* and therefore the first CF-part can run....